# Chilkat and Delphi 7 - post pdf file to a smartcard authentication site

Tags: delphi, http-post, delphi-7, smartcard, chilkat

Using Delphi 7 and the chilkat library, I'm trying to authenticate using a smartcard to a site and post a pdf file in order to get an upload index. I got lost in all that chilkat has to offer and I'm kind of brand new to this part of programming (using smartcards, SSL/TLS, certificates, REST, etc). How do I do this?

Here's part of my code, I got stuck at the post part.

```
http := CkHttp_Create();

cert := CkCert_Create();
success := CkCert_LoadFromSmartcard(cert, '');
if (success = False) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(CkCert__lastErrorText(cert));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Certificate not loaded.');
    Exit;
  end;

if (CkCert_HasPrivateKey(cert) <> True) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('A private key is needed for TLS client authentication.');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('This certificate has no private key.');
    Exit;
  end;

sock := CkSocket_Create();

success := CkSocket_SetSslClientCert(sock, cert);
if (success <> True) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSocket__lastErrorText(sock));
    Exit;
  end;

bTls := True;
port := 443;
maxWaitMs := 5000;
success := CkSocket_Connect(sock, mysite, port, bTls, maxWaitMs);
if (success <> True) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Connect Failure Error Code: ' + IntToStr(CkSocket_getConnectFailReason(sock)));
    Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSocket__lastErrorText(sock));
    Exit;
  end;

rest := CkRest_Create();

success := CkRest_UseConnection(rest, socket, bAutoReconnect);
if (success <> True) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(CkRest__lastErrorText(rest));
    Exit;
  end;
```

Here I need to upload the file using **POST**.

I tried to use `httprequest`, but failed, because I need to authenticate with the smartcard.

Comment: `= False` and `<> True` indicate you're _brand new_ to programming in general, not just _this part_. You also forgot a potential error code/message you got and at which point of your code your expectations fail.

Comment: @AmigoJack I used the code EXACTLY like Matt posted it in the documentation. This part of the code works. The problem is making a request using the smartcard.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the example to include the following:

```
// Set the certificate to be used for mutual TLS authentication
cert := CkCert_Create();

// If the smartcard or token requires a PIN...
CkCert_putSmartCardPin(cert,'000000');

success := CkCert_LoadFromSmartcard(cert,'');
```

You'll want to set the PIN before calling LoadFromSmartcard.